# How to serialize a list of objects, which are avro generated entity type

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, spark-streaming, avro

I got a serialization error when I try following code

```
public Result implements Serializable {
    ArrayList<AvroGeneratedEntity> entities;
    Map<Integer, String> stringMap;
}

public SomeBo {
    public void aMethod () {
        ......
        JavaRdd<Result> resultJavaRDD = rdd.map(f -> {
        });
        resultJavaRDD.repartition(1).collect();     // Error throws
        ......
    }
}
```

According to the error message, it is because the AvroGeneratedEntity is not serializable

```
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.testing.AvroGeneratedEntity, value: 
    .....

- field (class: com.testing.AvroGeneratedEntity, name: entities, type: class java.util.ArrayList)
    - object (class com.testing.AvroGeneratedEntity, com.testing.AvroGeneratedEntity@390fcb0c)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeValue(Serializer.scala:147)
```

Comment: Does this class implements Serializable ? Did you create this class or is it part of any library ?

Comment: yes, the Result.class is Serializable. It is a class created by me.

Comment: Please write that class also . Maybe it has members which are not serializable